# Find sequences between two words that are repeated - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the number of fruits and their names.
First I want to cut the string in substrings as I know where the sentence should start and finish.
After I will get the substrings, I can check the number and the fruit's name.
I will have an array with fruits' names and only one number per substring will be presented.

```
var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
var string = 'I want to <start> eat 6 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>'
var pattern = /(?<=<start>\s).*(?=<end>)/g;
var substrings = pattern.exec(string);
var fruit;
for(var i = 0; i < substrings.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++){
      fruit = substrings.match(/(fruits[j])/);
   }
  var number = substrings.match(/\d/);
}
```

I expect the output: 10 apples, 1 orange;

Comment: 10 apples is different from 10 slices of apple

Comment: Too many issues in your code. Please fix: 1) `pattern.exec(string)` -> `string.match(pattern)`, 2) `substrings.match` > `substrings[i].match`, 2) `match(/(fruits[j])/)` >  `.match(new RegExp(fruits[j]), "g")`, then 3) what does that lonely `.match(/\d/)` do? It will just match a single digit (the first in the string). And there are many more fixes required regarding the regex to use.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to capture  (number) anything (somefruit), as a regular expression, make sure it's using the global flag, this allows you to loop for each found section.   Using capture groups in your regular expression makes the summing up part easy..

So a simple regex for this is -> `/(\d).*?(apple|orange|kiwi|banana)/g`

Also note `.*?`, this is known as a none greedy capture, if not used it would keep on capturing until the last found fruit otherwise.

Below I just then use `new RegExp` to build the above regular expression.

Then because I use the global flag I'm able to traverse all found terms and sum.

> ps. Doing it this way doesn't require the start & end bits, but you
>   could add that in if really required.

```js
const fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
const string = 'I want to <start> eat 6 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>'

const find = new RegExp(`(\\d).*?(${fruits.join("|")})`, "g");  //build the regular expression
const sums = {}; //somewhere to store our sums.

while (true) {
  const f = find.exec(string);
  if (!f) break;  //no more found
  const [_, qty, fruit] = f;
  sums[fruit] = (sums[fruit] | 0) + (qty | 0); //sum the results.
}
 
console.log(sums);
```

Comment: It returns a error because lookbehind is not supported

Comment: @horcrux  Is this specific to some browser?, Chrome seems to work Ok.

Comment: @horcrux LOL, you could have said it's the OP code you was talking about.. :)

Comment: :-P I was still in pre-ECMAScript mode

Answer (score 1):

I made some edit to your code and it seems to work:

```js
var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"]
var string = 'I want to <start> eat 6 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>'
var pattern = /\<start\>\s*.*?\<end\>/g
var substrings = string.match(pattern)
var fruitsDict = {};
for(var i = 0; i < substrings.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++){
    if (substrings[i].match(RegExp(fruits[j]))) {
      num = substrings[i].match(/\d+/)[0]
      fruitsDict[fruits[j]] = (fruitsDict[fruits[j]] || 0) + parseInt(num)
    }
  }
}
console.log(fruitsDict)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape angle brackets they are not special RegExp operators (unless used with look around).

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues in your code (fixes with comments):

```js
var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
var string = 'I want to <start> eat 6 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>'
// we need .*? to match non greedy otherwise it will match whole string first and last <>
var pattern = /(?<=<start>\s).*?(?=<end>)/g;
while (true) {
  // we need to loop because exec return single match
  var substrings = pattern.exec(string);
  if (!substrings) {
    break;
  }
  var fruit;
  // you don't need a loop because exec will create array with one value
  for(var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++){
      // to create regex from variable use regex constructor
      var re = new RegExp('(' + fruits[j] + ')');
      fruit = substrings[0].match(re);
      // break the loop or you may have null on next fruit
      if (fruit) {
        break;
      }
   }
   // match any number of digits so it match 10 or 100
   var number = substrings[0].match(/\d+/);
   console.log({number, fruit});
}

var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
var fruits_re = new RegExp(fruits.join('|'));
```

You can also simplify the code by creating regex for fruits

```js
var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
var fruits_re = new RegExp(fruits.join('|'));
var string = 'I want to <start> eat 6 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>';
var pattern = /(?<=<start>\s).*?(?=<end>)/g;
while (true) {
  var substrings = pattern.exec(string);
  if (!substrings) {
    break;
  }
  var fruit = substrings[0].match(fruits_re);
  var number = substrings[0].match(/\d+/);
  console.log({number, fruit});
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would give the information: 6 apple, 1 orange, 4 apple but not 10 apple, 1 orange as requested by the author.

Comment: It returns a error because lookbehind is not supported

Comment: @eX0du5 your right I've only fixed issues with his code, using it like pseudo code. But to sum values is trivial, you can find this in other questions.

Comment: @horcrux it's supported by chrome. It's just fix to OP to have as small modification as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that firefox is antiquated wrt Google :-)

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

- match all patterns
- for each match update the result object

```js
var fruits = ["apple","orange","kiwi","banana"];
var string = 'I want to <start> eat 60 slices of apples <end> in the morning and <start> 1 orange in the evening <end> and <start> 4 more slices of apple before bed <end>'

var result = {};
string.match(/<start>.[^<>]*<end>/g).forEach(function(ele) {
    var n = +ele.replace(/\D/g,'');
    var x = fruits.find((e) => ele.indexOf(e)>-1);
    result[x] = (result[x] | 0) + n;
});
console.log(result);
```